# ASP:TextBox convert into bootstrap <input>

Tags: css, asp.net, textbox, sensenet

I've got a styling question on my hands. Using sensenet, a platform for ASP.net functionality, forms are done with not only sensenet language, but also ASP.net language as well.

I'm having a problem making the ASP:TextBox feature look like the bootstrap input box. I've called the bootstrap css file, tried changing the class for the ASP:TextBox code, but nothing works aside from just using the html tag of

```
<input class="text input-sm">
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="text input-sm" ID="InnerControl" placeholder="Middle Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

.. and the css is being incoporated here:

```
<sn:CssRequest CSSPath="$skin/styles/Projectname/bootstrap.min.css" ID="pageTemplateUIStyleReq1" runat="server" />
```

Is there anyway to make the ASP:TextBox to look like the bootstrap input box but also function the way it's meant to function through ASP language?

Attached are images of the before and after-sought effects:

what I have now:
[image: current effect]

what I'm looking to attain:
[image: current effect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are adding the class to your textbox is correct. The problem is here:

```
<sn:CssRequest CSSPath="$skin/styles/Projectname/bootstrap.min.css" ID="pageTemplateUIStyleReq1" runat="server" />
```

Just add a normal reference to your stylesheet and don't try to load it server side. If your page requires this, check to ensure it is loading bootstrap correctly in your browsers dev tools.

Comment: what do you mean by add a normal reference? just taking runat="server" out?

Comment: I mean don't try to include the bootstrap reference from that server control <sn:CssRequest... Just add <link rel... a normal css path to your stylesheet. If that is the only thing that server control is doing then you dont need it any way.